# How to make a search engine using elastic search and javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, elasticsearch

I need to use webstorm to create a search engine using elastic search, javascript and HTML.  DO anyone have a tutorial that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple search engine learn Elasticsearch PHP. Import your data in ES then start firing queries. For more info visit https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html